# How to Disallow `var drag` depending on `checkbox` checked?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, mootools, mootools-events

[Mootools](http://mootools.net): How to Allow and Disallow `var drag` depending on `checkbox` **checked** or not?

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
  var z = 2;
  $$('#dragable').each(function(e) {
    var drag = new Drag.Move(e,{
      grid: false,
      preventDefault: true,
      onStart: function() {
        e.setStyle('z-index',z++);
      }
    });
  });
});
function check(tag){
  if(tag.checked){
    //checkbox checked
    //How to Disallow Drag.Move for #dragable ?
    //Unfortunately so it does not work - drag.destroy(); drag.removeEvents();
  }else{
    //How to Allow Drag.Move for #dragable ?
  }
}
<input type="checkbox" onClick="check(this);">
<div id="dragable">Drag-able DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the instance of `Drag` in MooTools [Element Store](http://mootools.net/blog/2008/01/22/whats-new-in-12-element-storage/) so when the checkbox is clicked, we can retrieve this instance and manipulate it.

[Drag.Move](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag.Move) is an extension to the base [Drag](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag#) class, and if you see the docs, you will notice it has two methods for this situation:

- [attach](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag#Drag:attach)
- [detach](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Drag#Drag:detach)

You need to call these methods on the drag object that gets created when you call `new Drag.Move(..)` to enable or disable dragging.

So first create the drag object as you are already doing:

```
var drag = new Drag.Move(e, {
    ...
});
```

And then store a reference of this `drag` object inside the Element Store for later retrieval.

```
e.store('Drag', drag);
```

You can use any key you want here - I've used `"Drag"`.

Then later in the check function, retrieve the drag object, and call `attach` or `detach` on it depending on the state of the checkbox.

```
function check(elem) {
    var drag = elem.retrieve('Drag'); // retrieve the instance we stored before

    if(elem.checked) {
        drag.detach(); // disable dragging
    }
    else {
        drag.attach(); // enable dragging
    }
}
```

See your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/1) modified to work this the checkbox.

On a side note, if you are retrieving an element by id, you don't need to use `$$` as ideally there should only be only element with that id. `$$("#dragable")` is just too redundant and less performant. Use `document.id('dragable')` or `$("dragable")` instead.

Comment: @Anurag: Thanks! Unfortunately it is not working with `document.id('dragable')` http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/2/

Comment: @Binyamin - There were several errors in the link you gave. I sneakily changed the name from "dragable" to "draggable" for one :)
Then `document.id(..)` returns a single element, so you can't loop over it using `each`. I have updated your example here - http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/3/ so you can compare your version with this. Also, keep on the lookout for console logs using Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome/Safari. They are very helpful in seeing what went wrong.

Comment: @Anurag: I add there also `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` events http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/4/, and tried to make `mouseleave` event Disallow if checkbox checked, but it is not working. Could you please help me to fix it!? Thank you very, very much!

Comment: I was trying to Disallow `mouseleave` event if checkbox checked, not `drag`, and http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/4/ is not working. !? In http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/5/ it stops `drag` event.

Comment: @Anurag: Do you have some solution?

Comment: @Binyamin - I don't understand what you are trying to do on `mouseleave`. Could you describe in more details what is it that you're trying to do there?

Comment: @Anurag: I get already right answer http://jsfiddle.net/89RJp/6/ in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222504/mootools-how-to-disallow-mouseenter-and-mouseleave-event-when-checkbox-check/3222678#3222678